# MonoTouch CALayer BackgroundFilters

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, xamarin

I am not seeing the background filters collection on CALayer in MonoTouch. Is this just missing form the bindings? How can I add it?

Answer (score 1):

From the [Core Animation Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/LayerStyleProperties/LayerStyleProperties.html)

> Platform Note: In iOS, the backgroundFilters property is exposed in
>   the CALayer class but the filters you assign to this property are
>   ignored.